# Swift Data convert to UInt64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I read some Apple docs but I can't do the thing in object. I'm receiving through bluetooth a unix timestamp value in a variable of type Data and I wan't to convert it to an UInt64 var to populate an UIDatePicker but the function I implemented gives me the error :
"Fatal error: UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load out of bounds"

Do you have any suggestion? I'm using Swift 5.1

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    private func setDate(value: Data) {
        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(value.uint64))
        datePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Data {
    var uint64: UInt64 {
        withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt64.self) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind doing `print("data: \(value.map({ String(format: "%02hhX", $0) }).joined())")` and give us the output?

Comment: Can you print your data bytes? `print(Array(value))`. Btw you probably need to divide your time interval value by 1000

Comment: The result of the print is: data: 00000000 (4 bytes)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and post the 4 bytes you are trying to convert to Date? How would you expect to convert [0,0,0,0] to Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your bluetooth device will only send little endian four byte value, that’s obviously only 32 bits. I’m not sure why you’d try to extract a `UInt64` from something that you know is just a `UInt32` (or some other 32-bit type). So I’d suggest:

```
extension Data {
    var uint32: UInt32 { 
        withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self) }
    }
}
```

Or you can make the endianness explicit:

```
extension Data {
    var uint32: UInt32 { 
        withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt32.self).littleEndian }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this solution but I get an error: "Fatal error: UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load out of bounds". If I print the Data received is: 00000000

Comment: @Alberto - I’d suggest printing the `count` of the `Data`, as you’d only get that error if there were less than four bytes (or if you accidentally left a `UInt64` in there).

Comment: Ok this seems to be the problem and I fixed it. Thank you!! One last related question, how to convert back uint32 to data?

Comment: @Alberto - `let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: numericValue) { Data($0) }` (or `let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: numericValue.littleEndian) { Data($0) }`)

Answer (score 4):

I get that error when there are not enough bytes in the data to form a `UInt64` (fewer than 8). It is likely that it is the case here.

One way to solve this is to change `uint64` so that it handles the case when there are not enough bytes. When there are not enough bytes, it can just pad the data with 0s until there is enough:

```
extension Data {
  var uint64: UInt64 {
        get {
            if count >= 8 {
                return self.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt64.self) }
            } else {
                return (self + Data(repeating: 0, count: 8 - count)).uint64
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming a little-endian device and little-endian data. If the data is big-endian:

```
extension Data {
  var uint64: UInt64 {
        get {
            if count >= 8 {
                return self.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: UInt64.self).bigEndian }
            } else {
                return (Data(repeating: 0, count: 8 - count) + self).uint64
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or, if you can, fix this problem on your bluetooth device, so that it always sends 8 bytes.

Comment: Don't manually handle the endianness. There's existing initializes on all the integer types for that.

Comment: The payload from the device is little endian. I know the data it sends is 4 bytes but a unix timestamp could be also a UInt64, am I right?

Comment: @Alberto If four bytes, that’s obviously only 32 bits. It could be `UInt32` or it could be `Float`/`Float32`.

Comment: @Alberto A Unix timestamp _could_ be a `UInt64`, but that's irrelevant here. What's relevant is that you only have 4 bytes, while to make a `UInt64`, you need 8. That's why you should either pad the `Data`, or make it send 8 bytes so that your code can handle it more easily, or make your code accept a `UInt32` if you know the device _always_ sends 4 bytes.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes I'm sure that the device always sends 4 bytes for that parameter

Comment: @Alberto That's easy then. Just `load` as a `UInt32`. And if you _really_ want a `UInt64`, call `UInt64.init` in your swift code.